# xsl:character-map to replace with another special character

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have a text like this.

```
1' x 10&#34;
```

I just want to replace 'double quote' with xml safe character. So I change my code like this.

```
<xsl:output-character character="&#34;" string="&quot;"/>
```

My expected output like this :

```
1' x 10"&quot;
```

Reason I need this output, assign to a Client Data-set in later stage. But the actual result is :

```
1' x 10"
```

This result cannot assign to a Client Data-set. Is there a way to fix this issue. ?

**Some additional info** :

I used Saxon for transformation. Before I use Saxon I got output as I wanted (`1' x 10"&quot;`) without any errors. Saxon changed all special characters with ascii codes. I would like to keep Saxon for better performance.

Is that possible get xml safe entities instead of ascii direct from saxon.?

Comment: What is the output method? And you say you want to replace the double quote, yet in your example you show the input `1' x 10"` and the output `1' x 10"&quot;` so there you have the literal double quote and the entity reference.

Comment: Just edited my question. output method is xml - I need to get entity reference as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<xsl:output-character character="&#34;" string="&amp;quot;"/>`.